# How to set values for Radio button in android?

Tags: java, android, android-radiogroup, android-radiobutton

I am getting the value from DB and setting it to the respective button in the below format. Is there any optimised way to do the same. All these radio buttons are inside a radio group.

```
if (bundlevalue.get(3).equalsIgnoreCase("Mr.")) {
 rg_nametitle.check(R.id.mr);
} else if (bundlevalue.get(3).equalsIgnoreCase("Mrs.")) {
rg_nametitle.check(R.id.mrs);
} else if (bundlevalue.get(3).equalsIgnoreCase("Ms.")) {
rg_nametitle.check(R.id.ms);
} else {
rg_nametitle.check(R.id.messrs);
}
```

Comment: You can use `switch-case` statement with string case if you are using java 1.7

Answer (score 1):

You can try as follows...

```
String value = bundlevalue.get(3)
Resources res = getResources();

if (value.equalsIgnoreCase("Mr.") || value.equalsIgnoreCase("Mrs.") || value.equalsIgnoreCase("Ms.")) {

    String[] splitedValue = value.toLowerCase ().split(".");
    int id = res.getIdentifier(splitedValue[0], "id", getContext().getPackageName());
    rg_nametitle.check(id);

} else {

    rg_nametitle.check(R.id.messrs);

}
```

Comment: I am getting this error The method getIdentifier(String, String, String) in the type Resources is not applicable for the arguments (String[], String, String)

Comment: I have updated my answer. Sorry for my inconvenience.

Answer (score 0):

In case if you use `XML` attribute like this :

```
<RadioGroup
...
...
android:checkedButton="@+id/IdOfTheRadioButtonInsideThatTobeChecked"
... >....</RadioGroup>
```

or you can use `switch-case` statement like this :

```
public void onRadioButtonClicked(View view) {
    // Is the button now checked?
    boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

    // Check which radio button was clicked
    switch(view.getId()) {
        case R.id.radio_pirates:
            if (checked)
                // Pirates are the best
            break;
        case R.id.radio_ninjas:
            if (checked)
                // Ninjas rule
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `switch` statement. Although, there is nothing big difference in using `if-else` or `switch`, you can go ahead with whichever is more readable to you.

```
public enum Title
 {
     Mr, Mrs, Ms;
 }

String title = bundlevalue.get(3).equalsIgnoreCase("Mr.");

switch(Title.valueOf(title)) {
    case Mr:
        rg_nametitle.check(R.id.mr);
        break;
    case Ms:
        rg_nametitle.check(R.id.ms);
        break;
    case Mrs:
        rg_nametitle.check(R.id.mrs);
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```