# Android: Can you assign values to a radio button?

Tags: java, android, radio-button

I'm fairly new to android Java and I was wondering if you could assign a value to a radio button, check box or button like you can with HTML?

I have data coming from MySQL which I would like to be assigned to radio buttons.

Comment: What do you mean by assign value? put a label to it or set an identifier?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22828675/how-to-set-values-for-radio-button-in-android [Duplicate]

Comment: you can use `setTag()` and `getTag()` to store the values (Object) and get it later, https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes that is possible in Android.You can add it dynamically(programmatically) in the code.Refer the below link for how to do it   [How to add radio button dynamically as per the given number of counts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19380526/how-to-add-radio-button-dynamically-as-per-the-given-number-of-counts)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can assign value to radio button , Check box and Buttons.
Please follow a good tutorial for android.
Please check this [Link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls.html)

Hope this helps.